# Elements in HTML Lining Issue

Tags: html, css

So I have a pretty simple block of code for html where I put an image and piece of linked text next to each other using Angular 2. The problem is that the piece of text appears next to the image, however, it appears at the bottom rather than the top. I've tried using span to fix it but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lzCUfMY44QQ/WPNzcZpufoI/AAAAAAAADXE/CjLE9N_HRpIcXHKZfXDQrkRGD-mib_DzQCEwYBhgL/w140-h140-p/Logomakr_4ALcwz.png" alt="JC" width="65" height="400">
  <a href="../" class="navbar-brand" routerLink="main-screen">
    CubeTheWeb
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align`

Comment: As @jhpratt said. More specifically, `.navbar-brand {vertical-align:top;}` will fix this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lzCUfMY44QQ/WPNzcZpufoI/AAAAAAAADXE/CjLE9N_HRpIcXHKZfXDQrkRGD-mib_DzQCEwYBhgL/w140-h140-p/Logomakr_4ALcwz.png" alt="JC" width="65" height="400">
  <a href="../" class="navbar-brand" routerLink="main-screen" style="vertical-align:top;">
    CubeTheWeb
  </a>
</div>
```

try this

Comment: Explanations help. Code dumps *may* help OP, but certainly won't anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `img` elements are displayed as inline by default, which explains why the text in your link is displayed next to it.

Those elements are by default aligned along the "baseline". You can change this by using the `vertical-align` CSS property.

In your case, to display the text at the top of the image you would set `vertical-align` to `top` on the link.

```
a.navbar-brand {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
a.navbar-brand {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lzCUfMY44QQ/WPNzcZpufoI/AAAAAAAADXE/CjLE9N_HRpIcXHKZfXDQrkRGD-mib_DzQCEwYBhgL/w140-h140-p/Logomakr_4ALcwz.png" alt="JC" width="65" height="400">
  <a href="../" class="navbar-brand" routerLink="main-screen">
    CubeTheWeb
  </a>
</div>
```

Read more about [vertical-align](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/).